# Jasmine Test Knockout ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, jasmine, automated-tests

**UPDATED**

I've since updated my test and the error message coming back is very confusing...

```
it('Should get the available databases', function () {
        expect(vm.databases).toEqual([
            {
                name: 'DB 1',
                chosenRoles: function() { return []; },
                chosenModules: function () { return []; }
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 2',
                chosenRoles: function () { return []; },
                chosenModules: function () { return []; }
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 3',
                chosenRoles: function () { return []; },
                chosenModules: function () { return []; }
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 4',
                chosenRoles: function () { return []; },
                chosenModules: function () { return []; }
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 5',
                chosenRoles: function () { return []; },
                chosenModules: function () { return []; }
            }
        ]);
    });

Summary (1 tests failed)
x User Management Initial state Should get the available databases
    Expected [ { name : 'DB 1', chosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Functi
 }, { name : 'DB 2', chosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Function }, { nam
: 'DB 3', chosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Function }, { name : 'DB 4',
hosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Function }, { name : 'DB 5', chosenRole
: Function, chosenModules : Function } ] to equal [ { name : 'DB 1', chosenRol
 : Function, chosenModules : Function }, { name : 'DB 2', chosenRoles : Functi
, chosenModules : Function }, { name : 'DB 3', chosenRoles : Function, chosenM
ules : Function }, { name : 'DB 4', chosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Fu
tion }, { name : 'DB 5', chosenRoles : Function, chosenModules : Function } ].
```

**Original Post**

I am very new to running Jasmine Tests so this may be an easy questions but I am not really able to find anything that matches my situation.

I am using underscore to create a list of five objects in an array where in each object rests two Knockout observableArray().

```
var pfp = pfp || {};
pfp.insight = pfp.insight || {};
pfp.insight.controllers = pfp.insight.controllers || {};

(function() {
    'use strict';

    this.settingsController = function() {
        var root = this;
        root.databases = _.range(5).map(function (i) {
            return {
                name: 'DB ' + (i + 1),
                chosenRoles: ko.observableArray(),
                chosenModules: ko.observableArray()
            };
        });
    };
}).call(pfp.insight.controllers);
```

I am not exactly sure how to write a unit test that checks the initial state of the databases array.

```
describe('User Management', function () {
'use strict';

var vm,
    databases = [];

describe('Initial state', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        vm = new pfp.insight.controllers.settingsController();
    });

    it('Should get the available databases', function() {
        expect(vm.databases).toEqual([
            {
                name: 'DB 1',
                chosenRoles: [],
                chosenModules: []
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 2',
                chosenRoles: [],
                chosenModules: []
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 3',
                chosenRoles: [],
                chosenModules: []
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 4',
                chosenRoles: [],
                chosenModules: []
            },
            {
                name: 'DB 5',
                chosenRoles: [],
                chosenModules: []
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess the problem lies in comparing equality for `ko.observableArray()`s vs. `[]`s.  Perhaps you could break your test assertions up more along the lines of:

```
expect(vm.databases.length).toEqual(5);
expect(vm.databases[0].name).toEqual('DB 1');
expect(vm.databases[0].chosenRoles.length).toEqual(0);
expect(vm.databases[0].chosenModules.length).toEqual(0);
...
expect(vm.databases[4].name).toEqual('DB 5');
expect(vm.databases[4].chosenRoles.length).toEqual(0);
expect(vm.databases[4].chosenModules.length).toEqual(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The objects in your assertion have `chosenRoles` and `chosenModules` as javascript arrays.  But you are making them as observableArrays.  That means that they are really functions.

I might do what Mike Griffith suggests above, but remember to make the function call (add the parentheses) for the assertions (and change `toEqual` to `toBe` so that you get strict equality).

`expect(vm.databases[0].chosenRoles().length).toBe(0);
expect(vm.databases[0].chosenModules().length).toBe(0);`